# Why CodeIgniter do not set \n\r in my <form></form> input tags?

Tags: html, codeigniter

According this HTML source code generated by CodeIgniter,
Why, for some tags there are \n\r and for most of tags between < form >< /form > there no \n\r ? (for example the < a > and < /a > tags)

What should I do to have/manage \n\r ?

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">

<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <title>Chauffeurs</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/CI/CI220_FMT1/ressources/css/styles.css" type="text/css" />

</head>

<body>

<form action="http://localhost/CI/CI220_FMT1/index.php/CHAUFFEURS/chauffeurs_c" id="englobe_tout" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
<div id="div_menu_general" class="flexbox">

    <a href="http://localhost/CI/CI220_FMT1/index.php/ACCUEIL/accueil" class="bouton">Accueil</a><a href="http://localhost/CI/CI220_FMT1/index.php/BIENVENUE/bienvenue" class="bouton">Bienvenue</a><a href="http://localhost/CI/CI220_FMT1/index.php/QUI_ES_TU/qui_es_tu" class="bouton">Qui es tu ?</a><a href="http://localhost/CI/CI220_FMT1/index.php/TEST2b/test2b" class="bouton">Test2b</a><a href="http://localhost/CI/CI220_FMT1/index.php/TEST2b_mvc/test2b_c" class="bouton">Test2b_c</a><a href="http://localhost/CI/CI220_FMT1/index.php/CHAUFFEURS/chauffeurs_c" class="bouton_selectionne">Chauffeurs</a><a href="http://localhost/CI/CI220_FMT1/index.php/CONTACTS/contacts_c" class="bouton">Contacts</a>
</div>
etc.
```

This is the piece of code that generated the HTML code above for the < div id="div_menu_general" class="flexbox" > and the < a >< /a > tags (witch do not have any \n\r) :

```
<div id="div_menu_general" class="flexbox">

    <?PHP

    if (preg_match("/accueil/i", current_url()))
            echo anchor('ACCUEIL/accueil', 'Accueil', array('class' => 'bouton_selectionne'));

    else    echo anchor('ACCUEIL/accueil', 'Accueil', array('class' => 'bouton'));



    if (preg_match("/bienvenue/i", current_url()))
            echo anchor('BIENVENUE/bienvenue', 'Bienvenue', array('class' => 'bouton_selectionne'));
    else    echo anchor('BIENVENUE/bienvenue', 'Bienvenue', array('class' => 'bouton'));



    if (preg_match("/qui_es_tu/i", current_url()))
            echo anchor('QUI_ES_TU/qui_es_tu', 'Qui es tu ?', array('class' => 'bouton_selectionne'));
    else    echo anchor('QUI_ES_TU/qui_es_tu', 'Qui es tu ?', array('class' => 'bouton'));



    if (preg_match("/test2b/i", current_url()))
            echo anchor('TEST2b/test2b', 'Test2b', array('class' => 'bouton_selectionne'));
    else    echo anchor('TEST2b/test2b', 'Test2b', array('class' => 'bouton'));



    if (preg_match("/test2b_c/i", current_url()))
            echo anchor('TEST2b_mvc/test2b_c', 'Test2b_c', array('class' => 'bouton_selectionne'));
    else    echo anchor('TEST2b_mvc/test2b_c', 'Test2b_c', array('class' => 'bouton'));



    if (preg_match("/chauffeurs/i", current_url()))
            echo anchor('CHAUFFEURS/chauffeurs_c', 'Chauffeurs', array('class' => 'bouton_selectionne'));
    else    echo anchor('CHAUFFEURS/chauffeurs_c', 'Chauffeurs', array('class' => 'bouton'));



    if (preg_match("/contacts/i", current_url()))
            echo anchor('CONTACTS/contacts_c', 'Contacts', array('class' => 'bouton_selectionne'));
    else    echo anchor('CONTACTS/contacts_c', 'Contacts', array('class' => 'bouton'));


    ?>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to format your source code you either have to echo "\n" to insert a newline, or use CI's recommended formatting like this, where you insert php code into your html source:

```
<div>
    <?= anchor('ACCUEIL/accueil', 'Accueil', array('class' => preg_match("/accueil/i", current_url()) ? "bouton_selectionne" : "bouton")) ?>

</div>
```

I also abbreviated your if...else.